# Take Old Key value, Find equivalent New Key value, replace cell with Updated Key value

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA, and am an extremely bad coder to begin with.

Essentially what I need to do is take a product key value, compare that key value in a list of thousands, and replace that product key value with the new updated value.

I am a picture learner so this is what I am working with extremely simplified:

[image]

V

[image]

V

[image]

I have some code that I am currently writing, and have tried looking up a lot of different built in functions that I can work with, but I am really lost.

```
 Sub SwapNumbers()

 Dim OldNumber As Integer
 Dim myrange As Range
 Dim NewNumber As Integer

 ' Select Current Cell
 OldNumber = ActiveCell.Value
```

My first main question, is how do I set a variable to be able to cover a row range so large? I know I will have to change the variable type if I change it. But I am thinking is it possible to maybe do a loop that might be able to run through every row in a certain column until it finds the number then stops?

```
 'Compare Cell Value (Old Number) to List of Numbers (Col 1)

 Set myrange = Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("A2:A1712")

 For Each cell In myrange

      If IsNumeric(Application.Match(OldNumber, myrange, 0)) Then
          NewNumber = myrange.Value
      End If

 Next
```

If that is the case, once I find that cell, how do I save it to then make sure I can move over to a new column to find the new product key value?
'If found Old number match (Col 1) jump to New number (Col 2)

And I guess this next part is pretty simple, I just have to figure out the correct syntax....

```
 'Input New number (Col 2) into selected cell


 End Sub
```

I hope this makes sense?
I feel like I am vastly overcomplicating this. Or maybe not making it complicated enough. Who knows.

Comment: Look into [`Range.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find)

Answer (score 1):

I've gone overboard with the comments so that your 'newness' to VBA doesn't impede your understanding:

```
Sub SwapNumbers()
    Dim src As Range 'reference old data on worksheet
    Dim srcArr As Variant 'reference old data in memory
    Dim i As Long
    Dim current As Variant 'reference Match result
    Dim lookUp As Range ' reference 1st column of 'conversion table'
    Dim lookUpTable As Variant 'reference 1st 4 columns of 'conversion table' in memory
    
    Set src = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3")     'assumed location of cell containing 'Product ID'
    Set lookUp = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2") 'assumed location of cell containing 'OldProdID'
    Set src = Range(src, src.End(xlDown)).Resize(, 2) 'increase src for 1st 2 columns, and all rows (until blank)
    srcArr = src.Value2 'write src values to memory'
    Set lookUp = Range(lookUp, lookUp.End(xlDown))
    lookUpTable = Range(lookUp, lookUp.End(xlDown)).Resize(, 4).Value2
    
    For i = 2 To UBound(srcArr, 1)  'starting at 2 because headers in 1st position'
        current = Application.Match(srcArr(i, 1), lookUp, 0)
        If IsNumeric(current) Then
            srcArr(i, 1) = lookUpTable(current, 3)  'update with data from 3rd column of 'conversion table'
            srcArr(i, 2) = lookUpTable(current, 4)
        End If
    Next i
    
    src.Value2 = srcArr 'Overwrite src range with updated contents from memory
End Sub
```

(obviously the `Set src` and `Set lookUp` lines should be adjusted, as my assumptions probably don't represent the correct references of your actual cells)

Answer (score 0):

### Replace Numbers (Ids) Using a Dictionary

```vb
Sub ReplaceIds()
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const slFirstCellAddress As String = "A3" ' l - Lookup
    Const svCol As String = "C" ' v - Value
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "A4"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Write the ids to arrays.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    
    Dim lCell As Range
    Dim slData As Variant
    Dim svData As Variant
    Dim rCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range(slFirstCellAddress)
        Set lCell = .Resize(sws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data in column range
        rCount = lCell.Row - .Row + 1
        With .Resize(rCount)
            If rCount = 1 Then ' one row
                ReDim slData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): slData(1, 1) = .Value
                ReDim svData(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
                svData(1, 1) = .EntireRow.Columns(svCol).Value
            Else ' multiple rows
                slData = .Value
                svData = .EntireRow.Columns(svCol).Value
            End If
        End With
    End With
    
    ' Write the ids (numbers) from the arrays to a dictionary.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        If VarType(slData(r, 1)) = vbDouble Then
            If VarType(svData(r, 1)) = vbDouble Then
                dict(slData(r, 1)) = svData(r, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no numeric data
    
    ' Delete the arrays (the relevant data is in the dictionary).
    Erase slData
    Erase svData
    
    ' Write the destination ids from the range to an array.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    
    Dim drg As Range
    Dim dData As Variant
    
    With dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress)
        Set lCell = .Resize(sws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
           .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data in column range
        rCount = lCell.Row - .Row + 1
        Set drg = .Resize(rCount)
        If rCount = 1 Then ' one row
            ReDim dData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): dData(1, 1) = drg.Value
        Else ' multiple rows
            dData = drg.Value
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Loop through the values in the array to replace the old ids with new ones.
    For r = 1 To rCount
        If VarType(dData(r, 1)) = vbDouble Then
            If dict.Exists(dData(r, 1)) Then
                dData(r, 1) = dict(dData(r, 1))
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Write the modified ids back to the range.
    drg.Value = dData
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Old ids replaced.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```